# How to globally configure Moment to always format date as "DD MM"

Tags: javascript, localization, momentjs

I have a text input field and I want to try to assume the date the user is entering. I simply pass the text to a moment object and check is valid.

```
moment(textInput).isValid()
```

When a user enters `07 09` moment defaults to assuming it's `month day` which would be `09 July` whereas I want `moment` to default to `07 September`.

Is there a way to configure this moment to always assume the date is input as `dd mm`?

EDIT:

Have tried

```
const dateObj = moment("07 09", moment.defaultFormat).toDate()
console.log("dateObj", dateObj) // Sat Sep 01 2007 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

`moment` is very good at detecting what date you put in, whether it's `07 Sept`, `07 09` etc. I still want it to accept any formats, I just want it to not assume the US format of dates and to always detect the first number as the date and the second as the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to globally configure moment to make [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) parse input that are not ISO 8601 or RFC 2822. (If you want you can have a look at [`configFromString`](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.22.2/moment.js#L2345) method in the source on GitHub page). Doc states that:

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, we then check if the string matches the [RFC 2822 Date time](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) format before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.

For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use [String + Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

So, if you have to parse custom format you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) or [`moment(String, String[])`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/):

> If you don't know the exact format of an input string, but know it could be one of many, you can use an array of formats.

This is the same as [String + Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), only it will try to match the input to multiple formats.

Please note that:

> Starting in version **2.3.0**, Moment uses some simple heuristics to determine which format to use. In order:

- Prefer formats resulting in [valid](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) dates over invalid ones.
- Prefer formats that parse more of the string than less and use more of the format than less, i.e. prefer stricter parsing.
- Prefer formats earlier in the array than later.

In your case, you can use [`moment(String, String[])`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) passing `"DD MM"` and `"DD MMM"` in the array of formats to make moment parse both `"07 09"` and `"07 Sept"`. Here a live sample:

```js
const input = ["07 09", "07 Sept"];
const formats = ["DD MM", "DD MMM"];
input.forEach((value) => {
  let m = moment(value, formats)
  console.log("date", m.toDate());
  console.log("ISO string", m.format());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Passing in multiple date formats has done the trick.

Comment: Glad my answer helped you! @downvoter can you share what you think is wrong in my answer? It's quite strange to get downvote for a detailed accepted answer.

Comment: @VincenzoC I overlooked the answer and downvoted, reading this again seems pretty good and correct, could you please edit something in your answer, "I can see see some typos", so I can upvote again for the answer, sorry :)

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher thank you for explaining the reason of downvote, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `moment.defaultFormat` and `moment.defaultFormatUtc`

See the doc [format section](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: I tried this to no avail. Have updated my OP to explain where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This I think this solves the problem:

```
moment().format("DD MM");
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. That just formats the date that gets passed into the moment object. i.e. `const dateObj = moment("07 09").format("DD MM")
console.log(dateObj)` outputs `09 07`. I still want the moment date object returned, I just want moment to know that the date comes first and the month comes second.